Skip Participant button and back button ignored on event registration
I'm not sure if this is due to the way the event registration forms and profiles are used, or something else, but if someone sets more than one participant when registering, and wishes to skip the a participant, the button is ignored, and the profile's 'required entry' is triggered instead.
When they try to back up to the original registration page, that is ignored also.   What eventually happens is that they are forwarded to the payment processor, or if a 'pay later', the registration is processed and saved.
I have the Smarty 4 entry set in the civicrm.settings.php file.   Using Joomla 4.4.5, Civicrm 5.74.4
Any hints or other assistance would be appreciated.
Neil

If you temporarily switch to use the dummy processor does it work? i.e. is it maybe specific to the processor? It works as expected for me on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org with the dummy processor.

Note ... I'm using Joomla ... not sure if checking on Drupal will act the same.
